# What do I do if I believe a user to be operating a sock puppet account?

Tags: discussion

I have, in my view, strong, albeit circumstantial, evidence that a particular user is operating a sock puppet account. It appears not to have been detected by any automated mechanisms–both users are still here.

The individual in question is not interested in collecting lots of rep but rather uses the account to carry out prolonged vindictive down-voting attacks. The down-voting account loses rep over time (due to the down-votes) and when it gets close to falling below 125, it is topped up.

Do moderators want to hear more details (e.g. via a flag)? Or do we just accept that if the automated detection scripts don't pick it up, then there's nothing more to be done.

Comment: Extortion.  Er, I mean, flag one of their posts for moderator attention and explain how you believe they are abusing the system.

Comment: Wow.  That's the most evil genius scheme I've ever heard of on StackOverflow.

Comment: Preparing pitch-forks. Awaiting instructions.

Comment: Oy. Definitely don't just rely on the automatic scripts. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear OK, will do

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Flag an answer or question by one of the users, link to the other user, and (in this case) also link to this question. A moderator or an employee will then be able to review the users to see if your suspicions are valid.

Comment: True, but then mortals like myself don't get to hear the nifty details ;-)