# Down-vote unjustly

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

The down-vote is sometimes misused by users for reasons best known to them not because the question/ answer is not actually helpful.

What can i do if my question or answer is down-voted unjustly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. If you have ruled out all possibilities for a "justified" downvote (and don't just assume you have, really investigate), then all you can do is move on. Users are free to vote how they see fit, except for fraudulent votes.

Comment: If there is a downvote in between of 5 upvotes then it is probably a particular users' viewpoint. But otherwise there has to be something wrong with the question. SO monitors the behavior of users and if the user goes on a downvote spree then they will be reverted back AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

If you think that some user is abusing the system, you could try to get it to the attention of some moderator. Those cases have happened, see e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201756/multiple-account-user-got-pissed-off-at-me-and-is-down-voting-me-how-do-i-act#201756) or [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127104/how-to-deal-with-downvoting-sock-puppets).