# Busted or a Coincidence

Tags: discussion

On a site where its hard to get votes from user, I realized someone is getting average of 3,4 votes for last few months, today I though I might just investigate a bit and this is what I find out,

[image]

I "think" these votes are bogus because,

- Up voted with few seconds differences
- Up voted in a pattern where you search for old questions and get them ordered by date.

It might be a coincidence or someone else not the user himself doing it.

What I would like to know, as a member of site what are my responsibilities to report such kind of things ?

What are penalties if it's proved user up-votes his own questions using proxy accounts.

Comment: See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) for some info.

Comment: @BillyMailman it has been happening for months, system didn't caught this type of actions as its in picture

Comment: Oh, yeah. I agree that what you've found looks mighty suspicious, and seems to be passing the reversal script's checks. Your post read like you might not know about the existing systems, so I was just trying to give some background info.

Answer (score 5):

There are tools in place for moderators to find this, however if you find something that appears to be suspicious, then [you can always use an "Other"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118869/what-do-i-do-if-i-believe-a-user-to-be-operating-a-sock-puppet-account) moderator flag on any of the users posts and explain the issue. A moderator will review it and take action if needed.

If a user is caught using a "sock-puppet", then there are several things that could happen.

- The votes will be invalidated
- The user will be contacted by a moderator explaining that the use sock puppets is not allowed
- The user may be suspended

There is also a script in place to catch [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) and if the script finds it, the votes would be reversed. Unfortunately, the script is not perfect and there are cases when voting doesn't trigger the reversal.